# Multiple index matches with a for loop in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand just how a python for loop iterates. I know how to iterate with c++ but I have been asked to write this program in python. Forgive my knowledge in python but I am by no means an expert on the subject.

I've googled many possible solutions, however, they have not given actual guidance to my issue. Meaning that there was never an actual explanation as to how the coding works to iterate one by one and to be able to match 3 consecutive indexes.

```
for i in range(0, len(dna)):
    if dna[i] == 'A' & dna[i+1] == 'T' & dna[i+2] == 'G':
        protein_sequence[dna[i:i+3]]

//for i in range(0, len(dna)-(3+len(dna)%3), 3):
//    if protein[dna[i:i+3]] == "ATG":
//        protein_sequence += protein[dna[i:i+3]]

if protein[dna[i:i+3]] == "STOP" :
    break
protein_sequence += protein[dna[i:i+3]]
```

What I am trying to do is to iterate through and match an "exact" three character sequence. Once the sequence is found then I can iterate through by sequences of 3's until I match the "Stop" sequence. The for loop that is commented out didn't work either as far as finding the "Start" trigger to initiate the for loop. Thank you in advance for assistance.

Comment: But what are you actually want to achive? This code will find "ATG" in string and add "ATG" in `protein_sequence` list every time it will occure. Are you trying to count "ATG" in string?

Comment: @Olvin Sorry if I wasn't clear. What it needs to do is basically search the string of characters until it finds the sequence "ATG" then following it will use characters in groups of 3 to identify particular proteins until it reaches the "Stop" identifier. So when it finds the "ATG" identifier it will produce a match to the dictionary and then iterate through the entire list by 3's and each will produce their cooresponding protein. Then the "Stop" identifier stops the for loop. Not sure if this clarifies.

Comment: More "pythonic" way is to use regular expressions for this. If you still want to work with strings by indexes, check string functions in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html).

Comment: Unless you take it as a personal project to learn Python, you should have a look at [`BioPython`](https://biopython.org/) or [`scikit-bio`](http://scikit-bio.org/). These packages should help for manipulating DNA/RNA/Protein sequences.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, there is no such thing as a multiple index match; in case you need to look up the surrounding values of an element in an array, use a sliding window of size `len(pattern)`:

```py
def match(s, pattern):  # returns the FIRST match
  for start in xrange(len(s) - len(pattern)):
    if s[start: start + len(pattern)] == pattern:
      return start

  return None


idx = match(dna, "ATG")
if idx is not None:
  pass  # do something witty with it instead
```

Of course, this performs poorly on large data due to its time complexity of `O(n^2)`: you'll need to employ faster algorithms, like [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) or [KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify by using the split function limiting it to the first occurrence of ‘atg’ then doing your 3 letter loop:

```
dna='cgatgxggctatgaatcttccggtaatg'
z=dna.split('atg',1)
```

Output:

```
z
['cg', 'xggctatgaatcttccggtaatg']
```